# Can I copy from NSString to NSMutableString?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, copy

I have `strValue` as `NSString`, and I'd like to copy `strValue`'s content to another place.

The place is `mstrValue`, which is an `NSMutableString`. Space for `mstrValue` has already been allocated.

I wonder how can I use `memcpy` or `strcpy` for this purpose.

If it is impossible, I'd like to know other ways to do it.

Comment: There is a [good guide to NSString](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/NSMutableString) on the [GNUStep Wiki](http://wiki.gnustep.org). + stringWithString:, - initWithString:, - appendString and - setString: -- the latter two noted above, will do what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question isn't too clear but if you want to set the mutable string's value to the other string then do this:

```
[mstrValue setString:strValue];
```

If you want to append the value then do this:

```
[mstrValue appendString:strValue];
```

Both of these assume that at some point you did:

```
mstrValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Have a look at the docs for [NSMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There are lots of methods for updating its value.

Comment: I misunderstood that [mstrValue setString] returns an other NSMutableString. You're rignt. Thank you.

Comment: No, `NSMutableString setString` does not return another `NSMutableString`. It modifies the receiver. Look at the docs for this method. The return type is `void`.

Comment: I know it. You're right. Your answer made me look at docs and I realized the return type is void. Thank you and I'm so sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0):

I'll always prefer to used `[NSString stringWithFormat@"%@", strValue];` because then you clearly get a new autoreleased string and can dispose of string "strValue" correctly.

`NSMutableString *mstrValue = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strValue];`

OR

`NSMutableString *mstrValue = [NSMutableString stringWithString:strValue];`

Comment: Don't use any of the string format methods unless you actually have a string format to process. Your second option is fine but avoid the first.

Comment: Ya u r right but my intension is to get a new autoreleased string as questioner wants different instance of mutable string

Comment: Correct. Your 2nd option is fine for that. While the 1st does work, it should be avoided because you are not actually processing a string format. It's far less efficient for this use.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using memcpy or strcpy unless you want to deal with string encoding properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with object allocation:

`NSMutableString *mstrValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:strValue];`

You can do it.